# Current User Filter Web Part - Wildcard Filter from Multiple Names

Tags: list, filter

I have a list view webpart which contains a field which is a list of users, semicolon delimited. The field is a single line text field. I then have a current user filter web part which filters list items by said column, based on whether the aforementioned name is included.

If the column includes one name e.g. Joe Bloggs - all is fine.

However, for some list items it will be several names, semicolon delimited. e.g. Joe Bloggs;Jane Sample;Bill Gates

When this is the case, however, the filter does not function, and thus presumably cannot filter with wildcard.

Any ideas on how this could be achieved? Thanks.

Comment: the field seems to be multiloopUp. you need to use SPLookupValueCollection class to seperate the values in c#

Answer (score 1):

Sorted! Just used a Dataview webpart with a 'contains' filter.

If anyone else has the same prob, see [this link](http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=77):  - just follow that guide but replace text filter web part with current user filter :)